# Django Forms: How to edit fields that aren't on the model itself

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-admin

I have two models, `Foo` and `Bar`. `Bar` has a foreign key to `Foo`. From the Django Admin interface, I'd like to let the user edit the list of `Bar` instances that are linked to `Foo`.

My idea for how to do this would be to include javascript in the form, which would make a list populated by query calls back to the server. When the user clicks "submit" on the form, the list would do an AJAX call to make the proper updates on the server. The rest of the submission continues uninterrupted.

Does this sound like a good idea, or is there another way I approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is already catered for in the Django admin application.

You just need to create an InlineModelAdmin for your class.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects